# How to change the value of a submit button using php?

Tags: php, html, submit

I have recently been developing a multi-lingual website. The language is changed via an anchor tag using php. This affects all the text inside elements but does not so far work on attributes.

for example the Home button on my page gets its content from a php variable:

```
<li><?php echo $buttonHome ?></li>
```

That works fine but as I said this method does not work inside attributes, I tried the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $buttonSubmit ?>" />
```

I understand that the above code snippet would fail because attributes are not supposed to accept php or other scripts. They can only contain single variables (i.e  size="8").

I hope you understand the point I'm making here, basically how can I change the value of my submit button via php when a link is clicked (`<a href="?changeSubmit=NewValue"></a>`) ?

Comment: I notice that the ; delimiter is missing in every statement written in php. Could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: You can certainly generate the content of attributes with PHP. PHP is run server-side, and delivers finished content to the browser, so it'll never know where the content was generated from. Can you add a little more context? What is the value you're trying to add? What happens when you try it? Do you get errors?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The variable had no value, so my bad. The problem is now fixed.

Answer (score -1):

When you put some variable as HTML attribute use:

```
urlencode($variable)
```